# What is the significance of calling Mahalakshmi "Mahodare"?

Tags: scripture, gods, ganesha, lakshmi, symbolism

As we all know that Mahaganapaty is described as having a large belly.In fact one of His many names is "LambaJathara" or "Mahodara" literally meaning one having a big belly.

But in the Mahalakshmi Ashtakam  Mahalakshmi too is  addressed by the same name viz:Mahodara.

Quoting the relevant portion(stanza 6) from [here](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/devi_lakshmi-mahalakshmi_ashtakam.php):

> Sthula Suksma Maharoudre Mahasakthi **Mahodare**
>
> Mahapapa hare Devi Mahalakshmi Namostute

In that website the translator said big belly is to be taken as the symbol of prosperity.

I want to know what  other symbolisms/interpretations might be there behind calling Mahalakshmi "Mahodare"?.

Also, is Mahalaksmi mentioned anywhere in the Vedas as having a large belly?

I could not find anything of that sort in the Sri Suktam.

Comment: Perhaps one of the Ashtalakshmi manifestations has a large stomach, although I'm not sure if the notion of Ashtalakshmis has a basis in Hindu scripture.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I'm looking for more of a symbolic interpretation if there is any.Apart from Mahaganapaty and Mahalakshmi it is interesting to note that the planetary deity Rahu is also being described as having a large belly Although apparently this seems absurd because Rahu only has a head(although the body of serpent is attached to his head as his body).

Comment: [Directory](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%B0&lang=sans&action=Search) may help.